Hyperbolic Metric Space Inequality
Let $X$ be a $\delta$ hyperbolic metric space and let $c, c': [a,b]\rightarrow X$ be geodesics with $c(a)=c'(a)$. How do I show that $d(c(t), c'(t))\leq 2\delta+d(c(b), c'(b))$ for all $t\in [a,b]$.
I assume we split into cases. In the first case, we can assume $c(t)$ and $c'(t)$ are within distance $\delta$ of the geodesic joining $c(b)$ and $c(b')$. Then the result immediately follows. I am unsure on the other cases however.
